# ViewTreeObserver removeOnGlobalLayoutListener doesn't work

Tags: android, dimension

I add a ViewTreeObserver to one of my fragment in the onCreate:

```
 view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(viewTreeObserver);
```

I need only the first call to get dimension of the screen.
When the listener is called for the first time, I want to remove the listener but removeOnGlobalLayoutListener doesn't work.
Every time I change fragment, a NullPointerException is thrown from the listener.

```
    OnGlobalLayoutListener viewTreeObserver = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                // Only the first call was needed
                if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
                    view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(viewTreeObserver);
                else
                    view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(viewTreeObserver);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

You should remove listener by:

`view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);`

`view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);`